# File input is not triggering re-render after files stored in state

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a fairly basic "dropzone" component which should trigger the state to update and cause the files to be listed. Here is the basic logic.

```
export default class FileUploadModal extends Component {
  state = { files: [] };

  onSelectFiles = e => this.setState({ files: Array.from(e.target.files) });

  renderFiles() {
    // if no files selected, give them an input to select them.
    if (!this.state.files.length) {
      return (
        <input
          multiple
          type="file"
          className={styles.input}
          onChange={this.onSelectFiles}
        />
      );
    }
    // after they select files, I expect this to render instead.
    return (<div>YOU HAVE SELECTED FILES</div>);
  }

  render() {
    const { isOpen } = this.props;
    return (
      <Modal title="Upload Files" isOpen={isOpen}>
        {this.renderFiles()}
      </Modal>
    )
  }
}
```

However, it seems as though it never "clears" the input and puts in the div containing "YOU HAVE SELECTED FILES".

Here's where it's a bit bizarre: I put a log in render. `render` is re-running as expected. So I put a log in `renderFiles`, which *seems* to be acting as expected. It's as if the UI simply didn't redraw or something.

Why is this happening?

Comment: Could you provide a working fiddle or codepen so we can see the problem in action? What about React dev tools - can you see the components state updating? I'm no React expert but I'm fairly sure this is an incorrect way of initiating a state.

Comment: The way he's initiating his state is fine (he's using [ES6 Class properties](https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/transform-class-properties/)). But I'd say +1 for providing a working sample of the code. :) — @corvid: The problem could be you're using a class method (`renderFiles()`) and you don't bind it (`this.renderField = this.renderField.bind(this)`). Instead try with a class property (`renderFiles = () => ...`). Or remove this function and put everything in the render function (recommended). Tell me if it solves the issue, I'll post an answer. :)